# Windows Form Is Shown Blank When Opened

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

this is how the form shows when opened
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQsc7.jpg
what the form is supposed to look like
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EWRi.jpg

note: when in visual studio i did not start by making a win form app, this is for a private server for a game, its a .sln with 9 projects in it that all compile and work together, i am experimenting and seeing if its possible to do windows form in it, so far ive gotten good results, except for when i do the command (/wedit) to open it, the form shows blank, meanwhile in VS i have indeed added stuff to the form.

FrmWorldEdit.Designer.cs below

```
namespace WorldEdit
{
    partial class FrmWorldEdit
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.listTiles = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();
        this.lblSearch = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.tbxSearch = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.btnToggle = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.lblSelected = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // listTiles
        // 
        this.listTiles.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.listTiles.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(24, 69);
        this.listTiles.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(6);
        this.listTiles.MultiSelect = false;
        this.listTiles.Name = "listTiles";
        this.listTiles.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(512, 492);
        this.listTiles.TabIndex = 0;
        this.listTiles.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
        this.listTiles.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.List;
        this.listTiles.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.listTiles_SelectedIndexChanged);
        // 
        // lblSearch
        // 
        this.lblSearch.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblSearch.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(19, 28);
        this.lblSearch.Name = "lblSearch";
        this.lblSearch.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(138, 25);
        this.lblSearch.TabIndex = 1;
        this.lblSearch.Text = "Search Tiles:";
        // 
        // tbxSearch
        // 
        this.tbxSearch.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.tbxSearch.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(163, 26);
        this.tbxSearch.Name = "tbxSearch";
        this.tbxSearch.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(373, 31);
        this.tbxSearch.TabIndex = 2;
        this.tbxSearch.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.tbxSearch_TextChanged);
        // 
        // btnToggle
        // 
        this.btnToggle.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.btnToggle.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(24, 617);
        this.btnToggle.Name = "btnToggle";
        this.btnToggle.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(512, 45);
        this.btnToggle.TabIndex = 3;
        this.btnToggle.Text = "Start Painting";
        this.btnToggle.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.btnToggle.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnToggle_Click);
        // 
        // lblSelected
        // 
        this.lblSelected.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)));
        this.lblSelected.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblSelected.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 577);
        this.lblSelected.Name = "lblSelected";
        this.lblSelected.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(197, 25);
        this.lblSelected.TabIndex = 4;
        this.lblSelected.Text = "Selected Tile: none";
        // 
        // FrmWorldEdit
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(12F, 25F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(564, 685);
        this.Controls.Add(this.lblSelected);
        this.Controls.Add(this.btnToggle);
        this.Controls.Add(this.tbxSearch);
        this.Controls.Add(this.lblSearch);
        this.Controls.Add(this.listTiles);
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow;
        this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(6);
        this.Name = "FrmWorldEdit";
        this.Text = "World Editor Tool";
        this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.FrmWorldEdit_FormClosing);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.ListView listTiles;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblSearch;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox tbxSearch;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnToggle;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblSelected;

    public FrmWorldEdit()
    {
    }
}
}
```

Comment: InitializeComponent missing?

Comment: Someone else suggested that as well, I am new to this and dont know what that is nor where it would go.

Comment: We're going to have to see some code.

Comment: More to the point, your constructor for the form is where the designer adds the initialization code

Comment: InitializeComponent() is in the FrmWorldEdit.Designer.Cs still

Comment: Please put your details in the question, not in comments. Please include [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. Or at a minimum, you need to at least show all of the code being executed here (including your `FrmWorldEdit` class).

Comment: Also, it's not clear why you are showing your form in the way that you are; assuming your program is already a Winforms program, you should be able to just call e.g. `new FrmWorldEdit().ShowDialog()`. If your program is not already a Winforms program, then you need to use an STA thread to execute the code you've shown. Of course, you also need to make sure to not block that thread. In any case, there's just not enough information in your question for a good answer to be provided.

Comment: this isnt a winforms program, its a .sln project(s) for a  private server for a game, and i just did  right clck>add>windows form and made the form and everything and then made a command that opens the form, but the forms shows blank, just white, not what i added to it in vs..

Comment: @PeterDuniho How do I use an STA thread to execute the code, because thats what I need to do, its not a winforms program, its a solution with 9 projects that like compile together for a private server for a game.

Comment: The .sln isn't specific for WinForms or not, the .csproj is. You will need a Main that calls Application.Run(myMainForm) somewhere.

Comment: The real answer is that you will need to add a WinForms project to your solution and learn how to refactor and reference the existing code.

Comment: You need to create a new thread and call `SetApartmentState()` on it before you start the thread. Note that in the code you posted, it does _not_ call `InitializeComponent()` in the constructor, so that easily could be at least part of your problem as well.

Comment: Where would `InitializeComponent()` go, where/what is the constructor? I see `InitializeComponent()` on the `private void` @PeterDuniho

Comment: All due respect, if you don't know what a constructor is, you are already way out of your depth. If you know nothing about C#, it's hard enough to implement Winforms in a standalone program, with the Visual Studio Designer's help, . To do so as a component within a non-Winforms project requires special handling and knowledge about how threading and GUI in Windows and .NET work. To get you started: first, the _presence_ of a method is not sufficient; it has to be _called_ by something for it to do anything. Second, try searching for the text "C# constructor" on MSDN, Google, Bing, whatever.

Answer (score 10):

You have provided the content of the 'FrmWorldEdit.Designer.cs' file

Go to your 'FrmWorldEdit' file and make sure you have 'InitializeComponent' method call in the constructor, like so:

```
    public partial class FrmWorldEdit : Form
{
    public FrmWorldEdit()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Dont forget to remove your constructor from the 'Designer' file if will decide to implement as I have suggested. Otherwise leave all as it is, but dont forget to add 'InitializeComponent()' method to your constructor in the 'Designer.cs' file

Comment: The OP needs to also remove the empty constructor that is at the end of the designer file.

Comment: Yes, that is correct LarsTech, I have missed that detail. Either remove the constructor from the Designer file and add it to the other class as I have presented above; or leave the 'Designer' code as it is, but add the 'InitializeComponent' method to your constructor in the Designer file

Answer (score 0):

If the startup Form is blank and there is no compiler error.
Check if your **Program.cs** file is running the right Form, else it will run a form without context and will appear blank.

In this case the **Program.cs** file should look something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WorldEdit
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new FrmWorldEdit());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. The problem was that the changes in the design-tab wasn't saved. In your case it would be the tab called "FrmWorldEdit.cs [Design]".
Every change I made in the design-tab was gone after I restarted Visual Studio, even though I actually saved the changes. But after I restarted, the changes saved properly for further changes.

In the future I will try adding one small change and save and play to make sure Visual Studio works properly. If not, restart Visual Studio.

EDIT: This problem only occurred the first time I ran Visual Studio (after installing). It hasn't happened at all after the second time that I launched Visual Studio.