# C# Windows Form Is Shown Blank When Opened the .exe in other PC without VS installed, But .NET4 installed

Tags: c#

I am new To C#, Have created an application to program a device using serial interface. I tried to open the .exe in my own system (VS2010 installed) everything works fine. But when i open the same .exe in another system (VS2010 not installed, but .NET 4 framework installed (my app is created using this Target Frame)). the application opens as an blank page. Not Sure where things have gone wrong. I tried various forms solution like below:
[[Why do I get a blank form when I debug in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921300/why-do-i-get-a-blank-form-when-i-debug-in-c][1]), [[Windows Form Is Shown Blank When Opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33401278/windows-form-is-shown-blank-when-opened][2]). None of the solutions worked for me.

Below is my code for reference (There is a lot of design in InitializeComponent() Just typed one line due to limitation in characters. But have detailed all the calls done until the InitializeComponent()

```
namespace NormingPointTagProgrammer
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            var btMain = new BTMain();
            btMain.ShowForm();
            btMain.Configure();
            Application.Run(); 
        }
    }
}


namespace NormingPointTagProgrammer
{
    class NPTagProgrammerTool : BTTool
    {
        private NPTagProgrammerToolForm _NPTagProgrammerToolForm = null;

        public NPTagProgrammerTool(): base("/+NormingPointTagProgrammer+/")
        {
        }

        public override void Dispose()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        protected override BTToolForm GetForm()
        {
            try
            {
                if (_NPTagProgrammerToolForm == null)
                {
                    _NPTagProgrammerToolForm = new NPTagProgrammerToolForm();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                RaiseDebug(ex);
            }

            return _NPTagProgrammerToolForm;
        }
    }
}


namespace NormingPointTagProgrammer
{
    public partial class NPTagProgrammerToolForm : BT.Framework.Tools.BTToolForm
    {


        public NPTagProgrammerToolForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Data to Programmer fields disabled
            rsoDataToProgrammerGroupBox.Visible = false; // RSO Data - DATA TO PROGRAMMER
            indexDataToProgrammerGroupBox.Visible = false; // INDEX DATA - DATA TO PROGRAMMER
            WriteButton.Enabled = false;
            dataFormatWriteComboBox.Enabled = false;

            // Data from Programmer fields disabled
            rsoDataFromProgrammerGroupBox.Visible = false; // RSO Data - DATA FROM PROGRAMMER
            indexDataFromProgrammerGroupBox.Visible = false; // INDEX DATA - DATA FROM PROGRAMMER
            ReadButton.Enabled = false;
        }
}
}
namespace NormingPointTagProgrammer
{
    partial class NPTagProgrammerToolForm
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.tagIDGroupBox = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
            // 
            // tagIDGroupBox
            // 
            this.tagIDGroupBox.Controls.Add(this.tagIDTextBox);
            this.tagIDGroupBox.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial Narrow", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.tagIDGroupBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(138, 13);
            this.tagIDGroupBox.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
            this.tagIDGroupBox.Name = "tagIDGroupBox";
            this.tagIDGroupBox.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
            this.tagIDGroupBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(186, 51);
            this.tagIDGroupBox.TabIndex = 1;
            this.tagIDGroupBox.TabStop = false;
            this.tagIDGroupBox.Text = "TAG ID";

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox tagIDGroupBox;            
    }
}
```

Comment: why do not use std form: Application.Run(btMain); you should show BTMain class.

Comment: I have tried this option too didnt work Below is the BR Main Class code. namespace BT.Framework
{
    public class BTMain : DebugStatusProvider
    {
        public BTMain();
        public MainForm MainForm { get; }
        public string Name { get; }
        public void Configure();
        public void ShowForm();   }
}

Comment: BTMain is an important part of your code, it's a form? loads a new form? why are you declaring it as `var`?

Comment: Well var btMain = new BTMain(); is declared to call methods within the BTMain() class.  public BTMain(); with the class BTMain() has nothing to do with this

Comment: the only thing that you code do before starting main application message loop (Application.Run()) is create an instance of BTMain and call ShowForm() and Configure(), and nobody can see BTMain code. How can we help you?